# How do I replace the current working MySQL database with a .sql file?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to restore the current working database to the data stored in a .sql file from within Django. Whats the best way to do this? Does django have an good way to do this or do I need to grab the connection string from the settings.py file and send command line mysql commands to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import sql dumps through django; import it through mysql directly, if you run mysql locally you can find various graphical mysql clients that can help you with doing so; if you need to do it remotely, find out if your server has any web interfaces for that installed!

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't have any built-in commands for loading SQL fixtures. If you happen to have it in some sort of serialized file, like JSON, you can use the `loaddata` command of `django-admin` or `manage.py`.

You can read about it [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture).